# Error Accessing KeyValue pair in R

Tags: r, key-value

I am creating KeyValue pair as below:

```
    Market <- c("ESA", "CLA", "GCA", "DXA")
    Market_ID <- c(11,13,14,17)
    MI_KV <- setNames(as.list(Market), Market_ID)
    MI<-13
```

When I do the following, I get the desired output:

```
    > MI_KV$`13`
    [1]"CLA"
```

But When I do the following, I get NULL value as output:

```
   > MI_KV$MI
   NULL
```

How do I retrieve the value using the above command as MI will be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` and make sure to convert the object to `character`

```
MI_KV[[as.character(MI)]]
#[1] "CLA"
```